# Convert SQL Server 2012 database to MS Access 2010 

Tags: ms-access-2007, sql-server-2012

I have done all kind of tries. Naybe I have done something wrong. Can you suggest me how to import data from SQL Server to Access?

1. I did export from SQL Server (right click and task export)

I got errors like:

> Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the
>   Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.  (SQL Server
>   Import and Export Wizard)

1. I did import from Access and I tried thru ODBC connection and it also failed.

If anyone has the exact steps or any converters software link then it will be great.

Comment: This strikes me as an odd thing to do. Why not just link the table and run a query?

Comment: can you explain clearly..how link the table and run a query?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that but i dont want link, i want the copy of that database. when i export its giving that error.mean while i will even try that link

Comment: odbc connects doesnt support error while creating new dns file...

Comment: I am unable to create working DSN for SQL server.